# Get Oracle output in txt file in UNIX

Tags: bash, oracle, sqlplus, spool

I've below script, The issue I'm facing is that I'm not getting the sql statement output in the file.

I don't understand which part is wrong. Can someone please help.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo  "Start Date, `date`"
PATH= --*path*--
ORACLE_HOME= --*path*--
TNS_ADMIN= --*path*--

export PATH
export ORACLE_HOME
export TNS_ADMIN

FILE="/tmp/output_Oracle.txt"

sqlplus -S user/pass@service<< EOF
set pagesize 50000
set colsep ","
set linesize 200
set feedback off
set heading off;
set serveroutput off;

spool $FILE

--#SQL statement

spool off
exit;
EOF
exit 0
```

Comment: Yes, I tested the query and its giving the output

Comment: Is your "--#SQL statement" actually pl/sql and you are using dbms_output to create your output?  If so, you need to set serveroutput on.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got the issue. It was related to Path .